# Script de Calcular Por Dropdown sem onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Estou precisando que no *script* abaixo, ao selecionar o `dropdown` ele faça o cálculo automaticamente sem precisar clicar no botão `calcular`.

Outra coisa que eu queria é: quando marcasse o `checkbox` ele multiplicasse por 2 o valor total.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var i = function (id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

            i("calcula").onclick = function () {
                var c1 = i("campo1").value;
                var c2 = i("children-qnt").value;
                var c3 = i("iv").value;
                i("resultado").innerHTML = parseInt(c1) * parseInt(c2) * parseInt(c3);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="iv" value="2"/></br>
    <input type="text" id="campo1" value="10"></br>
    <select name="children-qnt" id="children-qnt">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="children">
        <button id="calcula">calcular</button>
        Result: <span id="resultado">0</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode esperar pelo evento de `keyup` no seu campo para atualizar o resultado. Esse evento será disparado quando a tecla for pressionada e solta.

Para tornar mais automático, pode esperar pelo evento `change` no `select` e no `checkbox`. Assim, o resultado será modificado sempre que for escolhido um número diferente no `select` e/ou o `checkbox` for marcado/desmarcado. Segue um exemplo:

```js
var $campo = byId('campo'),
    $select= byId('children-qnt'),
    $checkbox = byId('iv');

function byId(element){
  return document.getElementById(element);
}
    
function updateResult(){
  var result =  parseInt($campo.value) *
                parseInt($select.value);
  byId('resultado').innerHTML = $checkbox.checked ? result * 2 : result;
        
  /* 
   *  Isso seria o mesmo que:
   *
   *  if($checkbox.checked) {
   *       byId('resultado').innerHTML = result * 2;
   *  } else {
   *       byId('resultado').innerHTML = result;
   *  }
   */     
}
  
$campo.addEventListener('keyup', updateResult);
$select.addEventListener('change', updateResult);
$checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateResult);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="iv"/></br>
<input type="text" id="campo" value="10"></br>
<select name="children-qnt" id="children-qnt">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option selected value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="children">
  Result: <span id="resultado">10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: E como passo passar este result para uma variável ou um campo no php?

Comment: @FabioHenrique nesse caso é mais interessante você abrir uma nova pergunta, são dúvidas diferentes.